# Split function giving incorrect result in java

Tags: java, string, java-8

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public static void main(String d[]) {
        
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String s0=sc.next();
        

       
    

      String p[]=s0.split(" ");
      System.out.println(p.length);
}
}
```

I am using jdk version 8 and when i am giving input as "hello world java", it is printing length as 1 ,whereas it should print the length as 3,please help me in resolving this

Comment: use `String s0=sc.nextLine();` to read complete line

Comment: Hint for the future: if you think something as basic as `String.split` is broken, then you better make sure that everything you think about the inputs is actually correct. Such as printing `s0` to ensure it's actually what you think it is. Because almost always it's actually fine and your code doesn't do what you think it does in some other way.

Comment: When you have a problem like this, a good idea is to simplify your code to reproduce the issue. In your case, you could have replaced `String s0 = sc.next();` with `String s0 = "hello world java";`. You would then have realised that the problem was not with `split`...

Comment: As a side note, you should not use that legacy array syntax, i.e. `String d[]` or `String p[]`. Use the idiomatic syntax, `String[] d` and `String[] p`.

Answer (score 4):

`Scanner.next()` will get the input from the user till a space is encountered. For the input `"hello world java"` it only assign `"hello"`

If you want to include spaces also use `Scanner.nextLine()`